# VS Code Closing tag jumps to the left

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VS Code, I type a  tag, enter my code, press enter and then type the closing . When I hit that last > key, the closing div tag jumps to the left and I have to hit tab a couple of times to get it in place. How do I adjust this?

[image]

Comment: Is that only for HTML tags or other markup languages also?

Comment: This happens for other languages also, PHP for example.

Comment: Try to enable auto closing tags in settings (Ctrl + comma).

Comment: I already have auto closing tags enabled.

Comment: Still doing this to me in '21.  Most annoying when working with HTML elements in PHP files.  Tried a few things with no luck.  I'll post here if I find a solution.

Comment: Getting to the right settings. 
 Using "brackets" would ideally match indentation for simple things like HTML elements but it does not. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655546/manually-indent-needed-again-when-html-tag-is-closed-in-vs-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is caused by the "Auto Indent" feature of VS Code. To adjust this, you can go to the "Settings" (`Ctrl + ,`) and search for "**editor.autoIndent**" and change the value to ***"none" or "keep"*** instead of "advanced" or another value. This should prevent the closing `div` tag from jumping to the left when you hit the "`>`" key.

[image]

Or go to the "Settings" (`Ctrl + ,`) and search for "**editor.formatOnType**" and changing the value to uncheck that option or change it to false. This should disable the automatic formatting of your code when you type.

Furthermore, have a look over the [VS Code Formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting) post and the options listed there such as `Shift+Alt+F`, `Ctrl+K Ctrl+F`, and `Ctrl + Shift + P` to see if any of those will help.

Comment: More than two years later and this annoying problem is now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions I could find didn't help me (settings were already what they should be). What did help was realizing that this didn't happen everywhere, but specifically in blade template files, which are actually php files, where indentation different from that in HTML files would be expected. Installing the "Laravel Blade Snippets" extension then fixed this for me.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me too, leaving auto indent on full.

Answer (score 0):

this behaviour is controlled with settings editor Auto Indent.
Setting it to Keep will stay on the same indentation where you type the tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by installing the PHP Intelephense plugin